# Go MongoDB nested query with $lookup

Tags: mongodb, go, lookup

I have quite a complex query that I need for my project and can't seem to find a working implementation for it. My function below works, but now I need to add a `$lookup` statement to populate the profile object. As you can see every Match has a `PartnerA` and `partnerB` of type `Partner`. Every `Partner` has a `LiteOffer` witch has a profile. The profile needs to be added from the profile collection using `PartnerA.ID` and `PartnerB.ID` as the localFields for lookup.

Basically the issue is this: I receive one Partner.ID in my function which is also an id of a profile in a `profile` collection. Then I need to filter out all `matches` from the `matches` collection that have the same Partner.ID either in PartnerA or in PartnerB (only one of the Partners will have the same ID. The other one will have a different one). Finally I have to use mongo `$lookup` to retrieve the profiles for both PartnerA.Offer.Profile and PartnerB.Offer.Profile using the corresponding Partner.ID

Here is the Match struct (I cut out many of the fields so it would be easier to read):

```
type Match struct {
    ID        primitive.ObjectID `json:"_id,omitempty" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    PartnerA  Partner            `json:"partnerA" bson:"partnerA"`
    PartnerB  Partner            `json:"partnerB" bson:"partnerB"`
    Unlocked  bool               `json:"unlocked" bson:"unlocked"`
    DeletedAt time.Time          `json:"deletedAt,omitempty" bson:"deletedAt,omitempty"`
}

type Partner struct {
    ID               primitive.ObjectID `json:"id,omitempty" bson:"id,omitempty"`
    Offer            LiteOffer          `json:"offer,omitempty" bson:"offer,omitempty"`
    LooksInteresting bool               `json:"looksInteresting" bson:"looksInteresting"`
    Unlocked         bool               `json:"unlocked" bson:"unlocked"`
}

type LiteOffer struct {
    ID           primitive.ObjectID `json:"id,omitempty" bson:"id,omitempty"`
    Tags         []Tag              `json:"tags" bson:"tags,omitempty"`
    Profile      Profile            `json:"profile,omitempty" bson:"profile,omitempty"`
}

type Profile struct {
    ID          primitive.ObjectID `json:"id,omitempty" bson:"id" diff:"-"`
    Name        string             `json:"name,omitempty" bson:"name,omitempty" diff:"-"`
    Surname     string             `json:"surname,omitempty" bson:"surname,omitempty" 
}
```

Here is my function:

```
func getMatchesByProfileId(id primitive.ObjectID) (*[]Match, error) {
    var matches []Match

    filter := bson.M{
        "$or": []bson.M{
            {
                "partnerA.id":               id,
                "partnerA.looksInteresting": false,
            },
            {
                "partnerB.id":               id,
                "partnerB.looksInteresting": false,
            },
        },
        "unlocked":  false,
        "deletedAt": nil,
    }

    ctx, _ := db.GetTimeoutContext()
    result, err := getMatchCollection().Find(ctx, filter)
    if err != nil {
        log.Error("Could not find matches, Error: ", err)
        return nil, err
    }

    for result.Next(ctx) {
        var m Match
        if err = result.Decode(&m); err != nil {
            log.Error("Could not decode offer in getMatchesByProfileId", err)
            return nil, err
        }
        matches = append(matches, m)
    }
    return &matches, nil
}
```

Here is a pipeline that I used that works, but now I need to somehow combine these two queries into one:

```
    pipeline := mongo.Pipeline{
        {{"$match", match}},
        {{"$lookup", bson.M{
            "from":         "profile",
            "localField":   "partnerA.id",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as":           "profile",
        }}},
        {{"$unwind", "$profile"}},
    }
```

I hope this explained everything. It has taken me hours and I can't find the solution. any help would be highly appreciated.

If you have any questions feel free to ask.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have 4 collections (in the database) corresponding to each of the 4 structs? Or, is some of collection data embedded?

Comment: All of the match structure is embeded in one collection apart of the profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I managed To solve this issue myself and here is the function code:

```
func getMatchesByProfileId(id primitive.ObjectID) (*[]Match, error) {
    var matches []Match

    match := bson.D{
        {"unlocked", false},
        {"deletedAt", nil},
        {"$or", []bson.M{
            {
                "partnerA.id":               id,
                "partnerA.looksInteresting": false,
            },
            {
                "partnerB.id":               id,
                "partnerB.looksInteresting": false,
            },
        }},
    }

    pipeline := mongo.Pipeline{
        {{"$match", match}},
        {{"$lookup", bson.M{
            "from":         "profile",
            "localField":   "partnerA.id",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as":           "partnerA.offer.profile",
        }}},
        {{"$unwind", "$partnerA.offer.profile"}},

        {{"$lookup", bson.M{
            "from":         "profile",
            "localField":   "partnerB.id",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as":           "partnerB.offer.profile",
        }}},
        {{"$unwind", "$partnerB.offer.profile"}},
    }

    ctx, _ := db.GetTimeoutContext()
    cursor, err := getMatchCollection().Aggregate(ctx, pipeline)
    if err != nil {
        log.Error("Could not aggregate matches, Error: ", err)
        return nil, err
    }

    defer cursor.Close(ctx)

    for cursor.Next(ctx) {
        var m Match
        if err = cursor.Decode(&m); err != nil {
            log.Error("Could not decode matches in getMatchesByProfileId error: ", err)
            return nil, err
        }
        matches = append(matches, m)
    }
    return &matches, nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The aggregation query with lookup (runs in `mongosh` or `mongo` shell):

```
var ID = 'some_value'  // to match with the partner A and B ids

var pipeline = [

  // Initial filter on the 'match' collection
  { 
      $match: { 
          unlocked:  false, 
          deletedAt: null,
          $or: [
              { $and: [ { 'partnerA.id': ID }, { 'partnerA.looksInteresting': false } ] },
              { $and: [ { 'partnerB.id': ID }, { 'partnerA.looksInteresting': false } ] },
          ]
  } },

  // Lookup 'profile' collection and get the matching details for the corresponding partner A and B (of 'match')
  { 
      $lookup: {
          from: 'profile',
          let: { pa_id: '$partnerA.id', pb_id: '$partnerB.id' },
          as: 'matched_partner_profiles',
          pipeline: [
              { 
                  $match: { 
                      $expr: {
                          $or: [
                              { $eq: [ '$$pa_id', '$_id' ] },
                              { $eq: [ '$$pb_id', '$_id' ] },
                          ]
                      }
              }},
          ]
  }},
]

// Run the aggregation query, using the pipeline defined above
db.getCollection('match').aggregate(pipeline)
```